# Xcode Navigation controller bar color change

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uicolor, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealcontroller. I am trying to change the color of the navigation bar depending on the selection of the view.

It will only stay the same color of the initial bar color.

Any help guys? iOS7

Answer (score 0):

You will have each view as a separate class, and then change the navigation bar color programmatically within the `viewDidLoad`method.